# Why does `sys.stderr` and `sys.stdout` put a number at the end on the shell, but not in a module - python

Tags: python, printing, stdout, stderr, sys

Basically my question is the title,

so for example in shell:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write('Hello')
Hello5
```

(same with `stderr`)

But from a file:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('Hello')
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

(same with `stderr`)

So why is this happening???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the return value. `sys.stdout.write('Hello')` returns `5`, which gets printed automatically in interactive mode, but not in a script.

Comment: This can also be demonstrated by calling `sys.stderr.write('Hello')`, which (on my machine, at least) returns 5, prints a newline, and *then* prints `Hello`.

Comment: Wow, now i understand because in python shell it adds an extra print, so in module if i do: `print(sys.stdout.write('Hello'))` it will also add `5` to it, coooool, amazing